# About bijective functions

Tags: functions

> Let $f, g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be bijective functions so that $f(n) \ge g(n), \forall n$. Prove that $f(n) = g(n), \forall n$.

---

Actually I have a demonstration, but it is quite ugly. If you find an elegant prove, please post it.

Answer (score 4):

We can prove this quite easily by induction. Let $P_k$ be the statement:

$$
f(n) = k \implies g(n) = k
$$

**Base case:**

If $f(n) = 1$, then we have $1 = f(n) \geq g(n)$, and so we need $g(n) = 1$ also.

**Induction step:**

Suppose that $P_k$ is true for all $k < m$. Consider the unique $n$ such that $f(n) = m$. Then we have $g(n) \leq m$.

But $g(n)$ cannot be equal to some $a$ strictly less than $m$, for then, if $n' \neq n$ is such that $f(n') = a$, we have that $g(n') = a = g(n)$, contradicting injectivity of $g$.

So in fact $g(n) = m$

**Wrapping up**

So we have $f(n) = k \implies g(n) = k$ for all k. This means $f=g$

Comment: But where do you use surjectivity?

Comment: Both surjectivity and injectivity of $f$ are used where I say "Consider the unique $n$ such that..."

Surjectivity of $g$ is in fact not required - injectivity is enough.

Comment: In the base case, you suppose $f(n) = 1, \forall n$?

Comment: No, I choose the unique $n$ such that $f(n) = 1$

Comment: OK, I already have the same prove by induction, only a bit different